# Aggregating rows in a data frame and eliminating duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, aggregate

I want to merge rows in my df so I have one unique row per ID/Name with other values either summed (revenue) or concatenated (subject and product). However, where I am concatenating, I do not want duplicates to appear.

My df is similar to this:

```
ID   Name   Revenue   Subject   Product
123  John   125       Maths     A
123  John   75        English   B
246  Mary   32        History   B
312  Peter  67        Maths     A
312  Peter  39        Science   A
```

I am using the following code to aggregate rows in my data frame

```
def f(x): return ' '.join(list(x))

df.groupby(['ID', 'Name']).agg( 
  {'Revenue': 'sum', 'Subject': f, 'Product': f} 
)
```

This results in output like this:

```
ID   Name   Revenue   Subject        Product
123 John    200       Maths English  A B
246 Mary    32        History        B
312 Peter   106       Maths Science  A A
```

How can I amend my code so that duplicates are removed in my concatenation? So in the example above the last row reads `A` in Product and not `A A`

Comment: if you cast `x` to set first, then to list in your agg function, it will include only unique items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. First apply set on the items before listing and joining them. This will return only unique items

```
def f(x): return ' '.join(list(set(x)))

df.groupby(['ID', 'Name']).agg( 
  {'Revenue': 'sum', 'Subject': f, 'Product': f} 
)
```